# How do I join symbols in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've got a file at the path:

`:/equities/AAPL.csv`

I want a function

```
f(`AAPL)
```

that returns me the full file handler, including the `.csv`.

I've tried using:

```
.Q.dd[`:/equities]`AAPL
```

which returns `:/equities/AAPL` but I can't seem to get the `.csv` part.

I'm also very happy to use the primitives rather than the `Q` package (as this is just for learning).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one simple approach based on [sv](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sv/):

```
q){` sv y,x}/[`csv`AAPL`:/equities]
`:/equities/AAPL.csv
```

A more general approach for multiple inputs would be:

```
q)f:{` sv'x,'` sv'z,\:y}[`:/equities;`csv;](),
q)f`AAPL`IBM
`:/equities/AAPL.csv`:/equities/IBM.csv
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is amazing! If you wouldn't mind, could you kindly explain how it works (in English)? I'm trying to learn and am struggling with the syntax (I'm trying to build it myself from pieces so I understand fully).

Comment: It's two applications of `sv`, one `\` sv\`AAPL\`csv` to generate `\`AAPL.csv` and another `\` sv\`:/equities,\`AAPL.csv` to generate `\`:/equities/AAPL.csv`. The first approach does both `sv`s using `over` (`/`). The second approach applies both `sv`s explicitly and also uses a few `each` (`'`) to allow it to apply to more than one input

Comment: Amazing, I get it now! Thanks so much for your help, much appreciated!